# Who commands Operation Sophia?

Tags: european-union, military

Operation Sophia (formerly EU NAVFOR Med) is an ongoing [European Union military operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Sophia), established in 2015 to interdict refugee smuggling routes in the Mediterranean Sea.

Who commands this operation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The operation has their own [website](https://www.operationsophia.eu) and include their [Chain of Command](https://www.operationsophia.eu/about-us/#chain_of_command) at the bottom of their About Us page. Operation Sophia's current commander is [Italian Rear Admiral Enrico Credendino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enrico_Credendino). According to his Wikipedia entry and the entry on [*Operation Sophia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Sophia), he has been the commander since it was formed in May of 2015.

Strategic control of the operation apparently flows from the Council of the European Union's [Political and Security Committee](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/en/council-eu/preparatory-bodies/political-security-committee/). From the second page of the [published decision](https://www.operationsophia.eu/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Council-Decision-CFSP-2015778-of-18-May-2015.pdf) that created the operation:

> (10) The Political and Security Committee (PSC) should exercise, under the responsibility of the Council and of the
>   HR, political control over the Union crisis management operation, provide it with strategic direction and take the
>   relevant decisions in accordance with the third paragraph of Article 38 of the Treaty on European Union (TEU).

"HR" above refers to [High Representative of the Union for Foreign Affairs and Security Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Representative_of_the_Union_for_Foreign_Affairs_and_Security_Policy).

Comment: Thank you. That was lightning fast! What role does the European Union have in this mission? The chain of command lists only Italian and French naval officers. Put another way: who gets to decide when to end the mission and/or change its strategic focus?

Comment: @Ben [Here](https://www.operationsophia.eu/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Council-Decision-CFSP-2015778-of-18-May-2015.pdf) is a link to the published decision by European Council that created the operation. I am not an expert in the EU, but I imagine the same body that authorized the mission would be the same one to either modify it or rescind it.

Comment: @JeffLambert It appears the Political and Security Committee (COPS) sits between the Operation commander and the Council (see article 2.2 of): https://www.operationsophia.eu/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Council-Decision-CFSP-2015972-of-22-June-2015.pdf

Comment: This is the current chair of the PSC that authorises operations using NATO military hardware (like operation Sophia): https://twitter.com/sofiefrome?lang=en

Comment: I think there is a mistake in this answer: control flows from not from the "European Council", but the "Council of the European Union." Happy to be corrected.